# Rails, updating field via current_user model wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I really don't know why this doesn't work. It seems so simple.

The current user just wont update it's :active_lesson_page attribute when calling update_active_lesson_page(lesson_page) on the current_user.

Lesson Controller

```
current_user.update_active_lesson_page(lesson_page)
```

User model

```
def update_active_lesson_page(lesson_page)
  active_lesson_page = lesson_page.id
  save
end
```

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you realize that it should works?

here you define local variable

```
active_les.. =
```

then you save model with no changes

Try one of this:

```
update_attribute :your_attribute, 'new_value'
```

or

```
self.your_attribute = 'new_value'

save
```

Comment: thanks for you response!
I tried both before but seems not to let my tests pass. When debugging .update_active_lesson_page saves and returns true but when checking the active_lesson_page_num field it isn't updated. Also the update_attributes doesn't work. really strange.

Comment: it was in my integration spec... i had to reload the current_user. Thanks allot!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing active_lesson_page is a belongs_to association for your model in that case you should code your method in one of the following ways

```
def update_active_lesson_page(lesson_page)
  self.active_lesson_page_id = lesson_page.id
  save
end
```

or

```
def update_active_lesson_page(lesson_page)
  self.active_lesson_page = lesson_page
  save
end
```